# Groovy: separate spock test files from program files

Tags: testing, groovy

I have done a simple fizzbuzz program in groovy, using Spock as the test framework. This is done using a terminal and atom editor, in MacOs.

The code is here at my GitHub page: [here](https://github.com/hanfak/fizzbuzz-tdd-groovy/tree/7e9ad0fb4db06cf1be73906d90005fa0e1760648)

I want to be able to separate out the test files in a test folder, and the program files in the lib folder like below

```
-> FizzBuzz/
    -> lib/
        -> FizzBuzz.groovy

    -> tests/
        -> FizzBuzzSpec.groovy
```

When I do this and run the tests(using groovy 'tests/FizzBuzzSpec.groovy') it cannot access the 'FizzBuzz.groovy' file and it's contents.

How do I import or include the FizzBuzz.groovy file into the test file? OR do I have to do something else to make sure the tests are passing with the above file structure?

Answer (score 2):

You could switch to using a build tool like gradle

Then your code goes in `src/main/groovy` and your tests go in `src/test/groovy` and you can run the tests with `gradle test`

See [here for a simple Spock/gradle project](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example)

Comment: Thanks, had a few issues with sorting out the bundle.gradle file, but just used the example in the link. Also much faster than just running `groovy <filename>` for the specs.